# Analyzing foreign source code in R - How can I find functions / operators that are hard to google?

Tags: r, open-source, ggplot2, rcharts

Trying to learn something from source code. I stumbled upon "%||%" in `ggplot2` as well as in `rCharts`. Obviously the latter does not import the former, nor does it define "%||%" as a function. How can I search my R ecosystem for these functions? OS X' spotlight seems not to be the easiest solution.

Can anybody explain what it does and point to where it's defined?

Comment: Did you look at `ggplot2:::\`%||%\``?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks! Is it the same that rCharts uses? Because I was looking at rCharts and could not find where it gets the definition from because it does not import ggplot2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both of these cases, the function does the same thing.

Here it is from [**rCharts**](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/R/utils.R#L57-66):

```
#' Set a default value for an object
#' 
#' This function sets the value of an object to a default value if it is not defined. 
#' @params x object
#' @params y object
#' @keywords internal
#' @noRd
`%||%` <- function(x, y){
  if (is.null(x)) y else x
}
```

Here it is from "ggplot2"--slightly different syntax but same operation:

```
ggplot2:::`%||%`
# function (a, b) 
# {
#     if (!is.null(a)) 
#         a
#     else b
# }
```

---

For finding the definitions of these functions, you can start by trying `getAnywhere()`. Here's the result on my system:

```
getAnywhere("%||%")
# 3 differing objects matching ‘%||%’ were found
# in the following places
#   namespace:ggplot2
#   namespace:gtable
#   namespace:plyr
#   namespace:reshape2
#   namespace:scales
# Use [] to view one of them
```

Edit: note that [] accepts numeric arguments, not the package names

Comment: sorry for being so blind, which file is it?

Comment: sorry, not my really a good start of the day. Thanks for helping out though.

Comment: @MattBannert, no problem. I even highlighted the relevant lines for you in the link :)

Comment: I just thought, it's the link to the github repo that I know anyway. It seems that I am slowly gettin' my head around github's features.

Comment: OK. I added another little tip for you @MattBannert.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, a quick follow-up: when accessing internal variables using triple colon `:::`, does it ever matter if you use backticks `` or double quotes `""` around the function name. I just tried `ggplot2:::"%||%"` which works, but is it always the case? +1 for a great explanation. Cheers.

Comment: @AnandaMahto very helpful tips I re-worded the original questions so others might find these tips more easily.

Comment: @Henrik, See the last paragraph of `?Quotes` for why I've used backticks (`\``).